# Examine a text file and find string patterns using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to loop through a text file, line by line, and search for string patterns.  When I find the string, I want to do a find/replace, so I can make several updates in the file.  Here are the steps that I'm trying to get through.

Step 1, search for 'table_name', and grab whole line of text:

```
  - class: steps.validate.Validate
    conf:
      schema_def:
        fields:
        - data_type: FLOAT
          name: Month_End_Closing_Price
        - data_type: DATETIME
          name: Month_End_Pricing_Date
    id: standardize
  - class: pipe.steps.load.Load
    end:
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in your previous question - if this is a `yaml` file, you should just load it as a `yaml` object (basically python's `dict`/`list` data structure) and change the keys/values instead of messing with the string.  Is there some limitation for you to install the `yaml` package? You would eliminate a lot of this regex headache.

Comment: I looked into that.  I didn't see how that was going to help me.  Do you have a solution for parsing a YAML file, as I described above?

Comment: Most likely, but will need to see a snippet of the yaml file and what keys/items you are trying to update/replace/remove.

Comment: I just updated my original post.

Comment: It's still not clear how the document look like originally and what the expected results are.  Can you show a snippet of the original and the expected outcome? Perhap's it's easier to understand that way instead of pointing out all the string manipulations you are trying to do (since we won't be doing any if we rely on `yaml` data structure).

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit complex to understand, and equally hard to explain to others.  I just added a BEFORE and AFTER.

Comment: That snippet of yaml you provided isn't a valid yaml format.  Can you provide one starting from the root level? i.e. where there's no indentation? Also I'm guessing the output you expected should be a copy of the object? Or are you expecting to mutate the object in place? It looks like there's a lot of data manipulation in there (removed a whole bunch of config lines and moved some items around), so it's quite hard to tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: Is there another `-id` in the previous level of the very first `-class` you provided? From your snippet it seems `-class` is a sub item of another object.  The root is necessary if we need to manipulate the entire yaml.  For example I've made some liberal adjustment to your "before" (adding a dummy `- id` and `steps:`) to provide you a sense of [what `yaml` module can do](https://repl.it/@Etheo/TriflingFrayedMass).  You can see it's basically a nested list/dict where you can just manipulate the key/values as you see fit.

Comment: There was a prior ID, actually.  I just added it in.  I dind't realize it was necessary for this whole process.  I'm trying to eliminate a lot of the text and simplify this as much as possible.

Comment: Where should the 'steps:` fall under in your "after"? should it be under a `pipelines` or `id` in particular?

Comment: I believe it's just 'steps:
  - id: extract
    conf:'
And so on and so forth. Now, this file will be read into another system, which is looking for the format I showed in my original post.

Comment: As I see it you are not doing a concatenation. You are conjuring `extractor.Extractor` out of thin air, as it is not in the original (before) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after a lot of guess work I *think* this answer should be helpful, or at least point you to the right direction.

As mentioned, you want to use the `yaml` module to help you with this.  Once the config is loaded, it's really just a nested `list`/`dict` much like a `json` where you can manipulate the data easily.  [Here's my attempt to replicate your end result][1]:

You can play around with the data structure, but using this should give you *a lot* more freedom than regex.

Comment: Whoa!  This looks very, very close!!  I may need to make a couple tweaks, but this is definitely a million times better than what I had just a few hours ago!!  Thanks a lot for your help with this thing!!

Comment: No problem, it's just madness to manually go through a config file that already has a parser available.  With this you'll have a lot more control the do what you need now and in the future, because everything is structured already.  Good luck!

Comment: `yaml.load()` is documented to be potentially unsafe, so it is very unwise to use that here without any mentioning of that fact. Above all there is no need to live dangerously as `yaml.safe_load()` will do the job as well. You IMO should also point out that YAML 1.1, the version PyYAML supports, has been been long outdated (it was superseded in 2009).

Comment: I have to get my head around this stuff.  I have never heard of YAML until about 2 months ago.  I just need a little time to get up to speed with this stuff.  Thanks, again, for all the assistance with this!!

Comment: @anthon I wasn't aware of that, thanks for sharing really.  I'm rather new to `yaml` as well so I'm also learning.

Comment: @anthon what are some of the potential dangers of `load` vs `safe_load`? Does it not sanitize the data?